# Select results from multiple array elements in Json document with Sql Server 2016's OPENJSON function

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, open-json

Is it possible to combine parts of a json document from multiple array elements into a single result in Sql Server 2016?

Given this json:

```
{
  "fruit": {
    "types": [
      {
        "possible": [ "Apples", "Bananas", "Pears" ],
        "category": "Basic"
      },
      {
        "possible": [ "Oranges", "Grapefruit", "Lemons", "Limes" ],
        "category": "Citrus"
      },
      {
        "possible": [ "Blueberries", "Strawberries", "Cherries" ],
        "category": "Berries"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to see a single result of all the values from the possible element:

```
results
-----
Apples
Bananas
Pears
Oranges
Grapefruit
Lemons
Limes
Blueberries
Strawberries
Cherries
```

I've gotten close doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.fruit.types[0].possible'))
UNION
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.fruit.types[1].possible'))
UNION
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.fruit.types[2].possible'))
```

But this relies on tying the query to the number of elements in the array. 
Is there a way to do it without having to specify each array element individually?  Something like this (neither of these are valid expressions):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.fruit.types[].possible'))
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.fruit.types.possible'))
```

Is this where I should be doing a CROSS APPLY?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this where I should be doing a CROSS APPLY?

Yep.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)='
{
  "fruit": {
    "types": [
      {
        "possible": [ "Apples", "Bananas", "Pears" ],
        "category": "Basic"
      },
      {
        "possible": [ "Oranges", "Grapefruit", "Lemons", "Limes" ],
        "category": "Citrus"
      },
      {
        "possible": [ "Blueberries", "Strawberries", "Cherries" ],
        "category": "Berries"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'

select v.value
from openjson(@json, '$.fruit.types') t
cross apply openjson(t.value,'$.possible') v
```

outputs

```
value
---------
Apples
Bananas
Pears
Oranges
Grapefruit
Lemons
Limes
Blueberries
Strawberries
Cherries

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you.