# Parsing JSON stored in sqlserver object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve values from a json string stored in an sqlserver object using SQL. 
this is what I have

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE([JSOn_Field], '$.name')
FROM users
```

I am getting this error:

> Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of json_value function.

Comment: Why are you using Text instead of NVarchar(max)?

Comment: You probably need to cast the field: `cast([JSOn_Field] as nvarchar(max))`

Comment: how do I do that inside an sql query?

Comment: `SELECT JSON_VALUE(cast([JSOn_Field] as nvarchar(max)), '$.name') FROM users`

Comment: Thank you this is great it worked!!

Comment: How do I use the same sql query for a JSON array ? this is what I have 
              SELECT JSON_Query([JSON_Field], '$contactDetails.name')
               FROM users                                                                                                         I am getting all null values

Comment: Its not clear what you want and what is the structure of your JSON. But I think you need to use table function OPENJSON, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426043/select-results-from-multiple-array-elements-in-json-document-with-sql-server-201